# Trying to kill a CMD with a title with a BAT script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Used a lot of time to se if i could figure this out but no luck.

My issue currently is via CMD i can do

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Administrator:  Server2" /T
```

But i add this to a bat file, it removs the extra space between Administrator:  Server2 and for some reason that wont work ofc.

The thing i wanna do is being able to close down a specific cmd with a bat script, since that CMD runs a game server, and i dont want to target them all ad once.

Is there any way to only close the specific CMD?

Comment: What about `WindowTitle eq Administrator: *`?

Comment: The issue then is it would close both game cmd's with that, one i scalled Server1 and the other Server2

Comment: I see... perhaps you have a chance to determine the process ID (PID) using [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)`Process` and applying appropriate `where` filters, which you can use together with `taskkill /F /T /PID`...

Comment: not sure how to do that tho haha, aint a shark with it comes to batch scripts.

Comment: what exactly `removs the extra space`? I tested this command and it works as intended, found and killed the window just fine. Are you *sure* that your BAT-file is running with administrative previleges i.e. started with `right click -> Run as Administrator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "WMIC process" doesn't include "windowtitle", I reverted back 'tasklist' and 'findstr /l /c:"your string goes here"'.

The "/l" and "/c" together allow you to specify extra spaces.  Although I don't have an example on my system with the same number of spaces your example has, I recall using for something similar in the past.  Please try this and let me know:

## Cmd

```
for /f "tokens=2" %A in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" ^|findstr /l /c:"Administrator:  Server2"') do @echo taskkill /pid %A
```